# Is there any Portuguese word for "crowdsourcing"?

Tags: tradução-inglês, expressões-equivalentes, neologismos

I'd like to know if any word or expression that represents the word "crowdsourcing" exists in Portuguese.

The definition, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crowdsourcing) is:

> A modern business term coined in 2006, is defined by Merriam-Webster
>   as the process of obtaining needed services, ideas, or content by
>   soliciting contributions from a large group of people, and especially
>   from an online community, rather than from traditional employees or
>   suppliers.

Thinking about the similar word *crowdfunding* that is translated as "*finaciamento coletivo*", the best option that I can think for crowdsourcing is "*terceirização coletiva*", but this is strange, and I don't see it being used anywhere.

I know that this word is new (Wikipedia links its creation to 2006) and nowadays "crowdsourcing" is commonly used in Portuguese texts, but the concept is relatively old, so what was this business model called in Portuguese before?

Comment: Não me parece que haja só uma palavra para todos os usos. Por exemplo, há "consultas públicas" para quando o que é requerido são comentários da comunidade. Se o que é requerido é dinheiro, aí já terá de se usar outra palavra.

Comment: On a whim I tried constructing the phrase in portuguese similar to how it is made in english: composta de crowd (multidão) e outsourcing (terceirização) => **multização**. I was surprised: There is exactly _one_ reference to that word, actually used to mean "crowdsourcing", in the google search I did on the topic. Not bad for a made-up word. :)

Comment: There is a slang term for crowdsourcing which is "fazer uma vaquinha". Not surpringly, there is a [crowdsourcing site](https://www.vakinha.com.br) with that name. If slang is Ok, then I can write an answer!

Comment: Uma entrada recente no Ciberduvidas: https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/palavras-e-expressoes-equivalentes-a-crowdfunding/33922

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não devemos ter medo de fazer uso de expressões que sempre existiram em Português e que se adequam perfeitamente ao conceito que se visa definir

> the process of obtaining needed services, ideas, or content by soliciting contributions from a large group of people, and especially from an online community, rather than from traditional employees or suppliers

**Trabalho comunitário**

Answer (score 1):

Na [tradução do artigo na Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crowdsourcing) estão sendo sugeridas as seguintes traduções:

> ***Crowdsourcing*** (em português, **contribuição colaborativa** ou **colaboração
>   coletiva**), é uma palavra-valise em língua inglesa, composta de *crowd* (multidão) e *outsourcing* (terceirização).

Answer (score -1):

Eu diria que **crowdsourcing**, sugerido aqui por João Ferreira, pode ser traduzido como *trabalho comunitário*. Eu diria também que **crowdfunding** pode ser traduzido como *financiamento comunitário* (em português, digamos, "internacional") ou *vaquinha* (em português do Brasil); e que **crowdsolving** pode ser traduzido como *solução comunitária*.